# How do params work in Ember, especially when you have nested resources?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember with rails, and I have not had success trying to pass the parent_id param to get items from a database using the parent_id. The only way i have been able to retrieve has_many items of a belongs_to resource has been to have the parent model serializer return the has_manies. Does Ember require sending both the belongs_to model instance and the has_many model instances in a single get request?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. There was a bug that has been fixed ( https://github.com/Cyril-sf/data/commit/b113815dadb289b635065742faaf001be56dde77 ). Maybe you need to update ember data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Is there also documentation for this somewhere?